# .net Portable Class Library Contains Microsoft.VisualBasic as dependency

Tags: .net, vb.net, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I created a portable Class library, which should be used in a xamarin project, I removed the Microsoft.VisualBasic reference explicit in the Project.
Using the library in the xamarin project causes the following compiletime error:

> Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't
>   exist in the Mono for Android profile?Dateiname:
>   "Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"   bei
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)   bei
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)   bei
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)   bei
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute()

When I inspected the .dll-file with the dependency walker (ildasm.exe), I noticed, that Microsoft.VisualBasic is listed as dependency:

```
.assembly extern Microsoft.VisualBasic
{
  .publickeytoken = (B0 3F 5F 7F 11 D5 0A 3A )                         // .?_....:
  .ver 10:0:0:0
}
```

Can anybody tell me the reason why Microsoft.VisualBasic is still a dependency of the class library and how to solve this issue?

Thanks Ced

Comment: Are you creating a VB PCL? It is a valid way to create a PCL vs. the C# PCL. Otherwise we will need to see some steps of how you created this PCL.

Comment: Yes it's a VB PCL.
I created it this way File -> New Project -> Class library (Portable)
Then I selected Net Framework 4.5, Windows 8. ASP.NET CORE 1.0, Windows Phone 8.1 as target.
Finally I removed Microsoft.VisualBasic from the references

Comment: I think our docs on this topic should help: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/portable_visual_basic_net/ and https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/portable_visual_basic_net/xamarin-forms/ There are quite a few gotchas here, so please read carefully!

Answer (score 0):

Was curious since I haven't tried this before. Found some details that may help after some digging turns out there is a compiler option you can use -novbruntimeref (Old Code Project [Article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14953/Compile-VB-NET-code-without-Microsoft-VisualBasic)). Searching for that text give a couple leads that indicates that you can alternatively manually edit the project file and add line to the property group do the same thing.

```
<NoVBRuntimeReference>On</NoVBRuntimeReference>
```

Though some pages had the value as "true" instead of "on". But haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but adding this to the project file doesn't help :/

Answer (score 0):

You've to change the compilation options. Just switch Option Strict to "On" and the compiler will not bind Microsoft.Visualbasic. It depends on the late binding option which is a feature of vb.net and sometimes a problem!

Xamarin rocks ...